# c# WebResponse content length limit

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm trying to fetch a big file from internet with C# with `WebRequest`. So far all other stuff that I have is working fine, but it appears that some part in the middle of the response I get is removed. I tried printing out the `response.ContentLength` and `getResponseContent(response).Length` and I got `-1` and `80000` respectively. Is there a limit on the `WebResponse` length or it's the helper function that's buggy? How do I get the full content?

Here's my `getResponseContent` function:

```
    private static String getResponseContent(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        String ret = "";

        while (responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000) > 0)
            ret += (System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));

        return ret;
    }
```

---

Thanks to @Neolisk, I've re-written my `getResponseContent` to use the `StreamReader` class and it works like magic. Here's the code:

```
    private static String getResponseContent(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

However, still, can anyone explain why the the ContentLength in the response header is -1 instead some meaningful length?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but consider using a string builder. `+=` append is memory inefficient, because it creates a new string every time.

Comment: Because you are dealing with bytes -> String, you can use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class, should be easier a bit, using [ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Neolisk ReadToEnd works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the actual data you're receiving is, it's hard to be sure what's going on.

However - response.ContentLength is the header value from the HTTP response, which is the length of the response *in bytes*.

How many *characters* in a string that represents is not necessarily the same thing - many unicode type encodings are more than one byte per character.

Use the responseStream.Read overload that puts binary data into a byte[] buffer, create a decoder based on what the actual encoding is (set in the header) and decode your string from there.

Comment: But why does the header has -1 instead of some meaningful length? Could it be a server-side issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the return value from `responseStream.Read` to find out how many bytes were received.

Comment: `Read(...) > 0` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx `zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached`

Comment: @usr I was referring to the helper function that I wrote when I said it's buggy... but thanks anyway

Comment: @Neolisk yeah, he terminates reading correctly but he does not check how many bytes were read.

Answer (score 1):

The ContentLength is a http header. If the server side didn't send it you'll receive -1. It's not mandatory.

That's why using the ResponseStream is a good idea.